# Passing an object to a component

Tags: vue.js

In my parent, I have an array `items` and an index `selected` which points to the selected item.

```
 data() {
    return {
      items: [
          {id: 100, acronym: 'ABC', description: ''},
          {id: 200, acronym: 'DEF', description: ''},
          {id: 300, acronym: 'GHI', description: ''},
      ],
      selected: 0
    }
  }
```

And a component `item-editor` to display the item and allow edits:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['item']
    }
</script>

<template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
            <v-text-field label="Acronym" v-model="item.acronym" />
            <v-text-field label="Description" v-model="item.description" />
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

How do I then pass the item `item[selected]` to this component such that the component writes back to same?

e.g. something like this:

```
<item-editor ???="items[selected]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to send the data back up through a custom event.

in the child:

```
export default {
  props: ['item'],
  data() {
    return {
      myitem: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    childChanged () {
      // childChanged is your method of updating this items values
      this.$emit('mymethod', this.myitem); // emit to parent
    }
  },
  mounted(){
     this.myitem = this.item; // assign props to self
  }
}
```

In the parent capture the event being emitted

```
<child-component @mymethod="updateItems"></child-component>
```

and then in methods:

```
  methods: {
    updateItems(data){
      this.items[selected] = data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does data get sent to the child?

Comment: you are passing it through via props?

Comment: I just see in the child component `<child-component @mymethod="updateItems">` so wasn't sure how the information was being passed.

Comment: oh yeah, pretend it is being passed in through there. wasn't sure how you had your component set up.